# Proofs related to smooth dynamical system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Use the definition of a smooth dynamical system to show that $(\phi_t) ^ {-1} = \phi_{-t}  $.

Let $\phi$
be a flow on
${\mathbb R}^n$
and suppose the trajectories
$\phi_t(\overrightarrow {x_0})$ and $\phi_t(\overrightarrow{x_1})$
intersect.
Prove that the trajectories coincide.

Could anyone please get me started?

Comment: The word "smooth" is unnecessary here.

Answer (score 0):

$
\left(\phi_t\right)^{-1}$ is the operation that reverses going forward by $t$ seconds (or whatever time unit you use.
$\phi_{-t}$ is the operation that goes back by $t$ seconds. Clearly they are equal.

Suppose the two trajectories intersect at some point $x_2$ at time $t$. 
Hence
$$
\phi_t(x_0) = x_2, ~\text{ and }~\phi_t(x_1) = x_2$$
Now reverse time:
$$
\phi_{-t}(x_2) = \left( \phi_t \right)^{-1}\left(x_2\right)  = x_0 ~\text{ and also } ~=x_1
$$
Hence $x_0=x_1$ and hence the trajectories must coincide.

**Added in response to OP:**

$\phi$ should satisfy some form of composition law like
$$
\phi_{t_1} \circ \phi _{t_2} = \phi_{t_1+t_2} \\
\phi_0 = \text{identity}
$$
The exact form depends on the notation used by the authors.
Now set $t_1 = t$ and $t_2 = -t$. Then
$$
\phi_{t} \circ \phi_{-t} = \phi_0 = \text{identity}
$$
Hence
$$
\phi_{-t} = \left(\phi_{t}\right)^{-1}
$$

Comment: For first one, I like your explanation...how can we show that this is the case?

Comment: Not sure you can show it except use the fact that in a smooth system, time is reversible. What "group" structure do you have for $\phi$. Do you have something that reads $\phi_{t_1} \circ \phi_{t_2} = \phi_{t_1+t_2}$ or something similar. Not sure what notation you use

Comment: "Now set $t_1 = t$ and $t_2 = -t$. Then
$$
\phi_{t} \circ \phi_{-t} = \phi_0 = \text{identity}
$$
Hence
$$
\phi_{-t} = \left(\phi_{t}\right)^{-1}
$$" From the first equation to the second, I think the intermediate step is to multiply $(\phi_{t})^{-1} $ to the left of both sides of the first equation...However, how can we guarantee there is an inverse for this function?